# Непонятная ошибка yii2

Tags: php, yii2, http-status-code-404

Перенес проект на ноутбук и теперь выходит вот такая ошибка :

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException Class
>   'app\models\NotFoundHttpException' not found

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше в логи поглядите. Может там что конкретнее будет.... А также сравните версии `php` ........ sitecontroller можно показать, может там ошибка........... возможно в файле забыли добавить `use app\models\NotFoundHttpException`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс отсутствует в заданном пространстве имен

Замените строку

```
NotFoundHttpException
```

На

```
\yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
```

Comment: Действительно проблема была в этом, добавил в use и всё заработало.